# Share data to Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-sharer

I have to share data `new_link` as well as `news_title` I am able share data `news_link` But I want to share `News_title` also with `news_link`.

please tell me how i will do this Here is my code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+news_link+"&_rdr"))
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I'm not sure. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3515198) may be helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link can help you:
[Facebook and twitter share for mobile web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187016/facebook-and-twitter-share-for-mobile-web)
You just have to provide the "t" argument for title (when facebook API is not buggy)

Comment: can u please write that URL so that direct i can use it i.setData(Uri.parse(  ? )); please

Comment: "https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+news_link+"&t="+title+"&_rdr" please check is it right?

Comment: can u Provide for twitter also i m givng "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+news_link+"&url="+"https://www.taxmann.com"