# Share link not working on iphone but does on desktop

Tags: html, iphone, css, facebook, share

I have a share link on my website that works great in most browsers and mobile devices. For some reason though, it doesn't work on iphones. It brings up a share form in facebook, however the form is empty and

```
<a target="_blank" href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[url]=http://www.lcbcchurch.com/watch/series/cat/{category_url_title}&amp;p[images][0]={square-thumb}&amp;p[title]={exp:stringy:htmlentities}{category_name}{/exp:stringy:htmlentities}&amp;p[summary]={category_description}'><img src="{homepage}nimg/facebook-icon.png" /></a>
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Comment: could just be safari....@nate8684

Answer (score 9):

I have the feeling that it may not work because that sharer.php link will redirect on mobile devices to m.facebook.com.  If so you just have to add the 'm2w' parameter to your URL so the m. is not picked up.

```
 https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?m2w&s=100.... (etc)
```

The StackOverflow Question:
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377968/cant-use-facebook-sharer-php-custom-parameters-in-mobile-sites)

Comment: Nice, that did fix it. However, now I'm getting the desktop version. Any way to have the best of both worlds. I like the zoomed in mobile version, how do I get that to show up?

Comment: When I click on the example in the link below, everything works fine. Any thoughts why my link doesn't open in the mobile version? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/

Comment: I'm not sure what the s parameter is for. Could you try this:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.lcbcchurch.com/watch/series/cat/{category_url_title}&amp;p[images][0]={square-thumb}&amp;p[title]={exp:stringy:htmlentities}{category_name}{/exp:stringy:htmlentities}&amp;p[summary]={category_description}

This is the same thing without the m2w and using u for the url parameter like the Facebook documentation says.

Comment: Like Stephen said, just leave of the `https://www` part and let the browser decide for itself if you need the m or the desktop version.