# IOS/Objective-C: Share Dialog for App Without Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Given all of Facebook's api [changes since April 2018](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/), does anyone know if it is still possible to trigger a share dialog *without* using the Facebook SDK?

They give instructions on how to do it with the [Facebook for IOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios) here.

However, I'd like to avoid including the Facebook SDK in my app given its size

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Last time integrated the Facebook SDK, I ended up with 155+ warning. I like your idea of avoiding the integration all together.

Comment: I find their documentation confusing.  You can no longer use publish_actions permission.  But much of the graph api seems to remain as in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/user/feed

Comment: As for the share dialog, it is available to websites.  See accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547292/how-create-a-facebook-share-button-without-sdk-or-custom-app-idSo perhaps it is still available to apps.